# Is there a downside to upgrading to RoS asap

Tags: diablo-iii

I have base Diablo 3 PC version, and am considering upgrading to Reaper of Souls. However, I haven't completed all of the older content such as Infernal Machine available in the classic version - and from reading online, I know that the parts dropped by the IM bosses change in RoS.

As such, is there any reason to actually delay a RoS purchase to e.g. farm quests/bosses/etc. that may be unavailable or changed in the expansion?

Comment: No, no reason! Also, check out those sick 2-piece bonuses to class sets coming in [2.2.0](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/18061643/patch-220-ptr-patch-notes-updated-320-3-20-2015) and get ready for Season 3 at April 10!

Comment: @OrcJMR well it is interesting... guess I'll dust up my monk and try Inna's with an ally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another minor, but more permanent benefit, is if you sit at level 60 without RoS you will gain Paragon experience.  Paragon levels give all of your characters a boost like +Resist All for extra toughness, Crit Damage, Attack Speed, etc.  And the first few dozen Paragon levels require less experience than it takes to go from 60-70.

You would normally gain Paragon levels upon reaching level 70 with RoS, so this isn't a strong reason to hold off of the expansion, but if you wanted to buff up your alts and have an easier time in Act 5, it would be a side-perk while you work on the older content.

The biggest benefit to this delay would be for hardcore heroes, where you want every edge you can get.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you actually looking to create those Hellfire rings, upgrading would stop and prevent you from completing those rings.  There are also skill updates and gear changes would would normally break your current build.
So if you want that Level 60 ring set, I would hold off on adding the expansion to your b.net account till you are finished with your rings.

Comment: But considering that almost all of your gear will get obsolete the moment you hit level 61 (61-tier gear has kind of twice the base damage, and all other stats are greater, of course), you won't lose much. Also, there are only achievements for completing level 70 HF ring and amulet. If I were you, I'd save that time you'll be farming level 60 and spent it farming new content and getting upgrades there.

Comment: @OrcJMR Well, there is an achievement for completing one of the level 60 sets, and while you can still earn that at 70, there's fewer competing items at 60.

Comment: @Troyen, right you are, I forgot about that one. On the other hand, in RoS end-game you can generate legendaries far faster than in vanilla game (simply going into a Rift _doubles_ your drop chance, plus there's focused gambling for specific items at Kadala). I'd still advise to upgrade.

Comment: You can still craft the level 60 rings with RoS [but it will be a pain](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/13020992618) to get the mats as once you pass 60, they won't drop anymore. So it's not true that `updgrading will stop and prevent you from completing those rings`.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau I do not consider this game a Multiplayer.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you actually want a level 60 hellfire ring that badly, get the materials for it without RoS since you will be 60 and won't level up. Once you [got RoS and level 61](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/13020992618), level 60 hellfire ring's materials will be out of reach since you'll start getting level 70 hellfire ring's materials instead. If you have the materials for the level 60 and got RoS, you can still craft it if you start a level 60 game.

Same goes with the legendary drop from bosses, once you get 61, Diablo won't have a 100% legend drop as it will be [moved to Mathael instead](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/12185968584). Easier to do that without RoS then once all your characters have got their legendary, upgrade to RoS and level them up to get the legendary from Mathael.

Overall, I think upgrading is worth it. Troyen's answer might be the sole good reason to stay without RoS but, imo, it ain't worth it. The experience gained from doing all there is to do in RoS, the drop rates from rifts and greater rifts will be worth more than the time spend/wasted (depending how you see it) at 60 trying to get a hellfire ring that you will most probably end up not using.