# Can I still get level 60 hellfire ring if I have a level 70 character?

Tags: diablo-iii

I have a hard time finding people to do keywarden for level 70 hell fire ring.

Can I still grab level 60 hell fire ring?

Comment: It is possible but very hard, read my answer [to this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/211937/61395). The question is different but it covers the same thing. Probably duplicates.

Comment: can't u just level a char to 60.. open a game with it and leave  (join with your main char) -> game is lvl 60 (but u need more than 1 player / game instance)

Comment: Why wouldn't you want a level 70 Hf ring ?

Comment: @Jenson unsure it would work... been a while I've played but if the game stays at level 60, then yes.

Comment: @WizardLizard some people want a level 60 ring too for the fun of having it. Some say it's better than the 70's ones... I personally don't care about those rings but some do.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau Yes, the level of the game only updates when host levels up. So creating a game with a low-level char and then swapping to all-70 team indeed locks the game at its level.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. Just acquire the plan from Squirt the Paddler. You'll need some crafting mats, too. But these can be obtained in Adventure Mode by killing the Uber Bosses in New Tristram. To engage the Uber Boss fight, you need the Infernal Machines, which drop from killing the Keywardens.